# Javascript - Check if string have a special format

Tags: javascript, string

I have a text field and the user should insert there numbers seperated with a comma. For example:

1,2,3,4,50,100

How can I check now if the value of the text field have this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify your input using regex:

```
/^\d+(,\d+)*$/.test(value)
```